# specify char input only in textbox + to be able to use shortcuts

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, shortcut

I want to have a textbox in C# which accepts only digits. My way to do this:

```
    private void textBoxStart_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char i = e.KeyChar;
       
        if (!((i >= '0' && i <= '9') || i == 8))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

It works fine. But I want to be able use shortcuts (like ctrl + v). How can I do it?

## edit

I wanted to simplify my problem. But answer like "use numericUpDown" oblige me to show all problem. Exactly problem is to be able accept all digit, capital and small letter. NumericUpDown accept only number;p

## edit 2

I do it in winForms app.

Comment: You need to pass control to the base class KeyPress event handler if you haven't handled it and haven't explicitly banned it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numeric Data Entry in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511/numeric-data-entry-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Use a NumericUpDown box instead.

Comment: I wanted to simplify my problem. Exactly problem is to be able accept all digit, capital and small letter. NumericUpDown accept only number;p

Answer (score 0):

Check out the silverlight-specific numeric textbox.  Although it's Silverlight-Specific, this should work for all C# code-behind.

[How to create a numeric textbox in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268207/how-to-create-a-numeric-textbox-in-silverlight)

I ended up using Sameh Serag's implementation and modifying it a bit to set a max/min.  It's worked quite well.

Answer (score 0):

why recreate the wheel? you should [check out the masked textbox in the WPF toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox).

you should look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511/numeric-data-entry-in-wpf). seems similar to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, although it's probably an overkill...

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"[a-z\d]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
        // Successful match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b95b5197-e695-4e46-ae0c-9575c7c80c5b/

You could use a Validating or TextChanged event handler to verify the input after typing. For that task regular expressions should be good. This isn't perfect though as interrupts the user experience in some way.

I can think of no easy to use possibility to reject invalid characters right away. You should wait till the control loses focus or something like that.

Then you could try a MaskedTextBox but the Mask cannot take an arbitrary number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Lifted from [Simple Numeric TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/Simple_Numeric_TextBox.aspx), here is the basic routine:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  bool numOK = ((e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9 ||
                 e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) &&
                 e.Modifiers != Keys.Shift);

  bool editOK = ((e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V) ||
                 (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C) ||
                 (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.X) ||
                 (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back));

  bool moveOK = (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up ||
                 e.KeyCode == Keys.Right ||
                 e.KeyCode == Keys.Down ||
                 e.KeyCode == Keys.Left ||
                 e.KeyCode == Keys.Home ||
                 e.KeyCode == Keys.End);

  if (!(numOK || editOK || moveOK)) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Of course, by restricting keyboard input to just numbers but allowing for Control-Paste, you have a problem with controlling what the end user is pasting, which could be strings.  If you need that, look closer at the linked project-- you have to override WndProc and intercept the paste command and then inspect the contents of the clipboard.  That would require you to make your own control where you inherit from TextBox.