# How to get pressed character from KeyDown event windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app. I want to get the value of the key in which the user is pressing. I want check wheather it is a digit or any other alphabet or special charater. Because my text box is using for entering currency. So I need to prevent users from entering alphabets or any special characters. Only digits are allowed to enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I usually reject keystrokes

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.D1)
    {
        // reject this key and do not show in textbox
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** See [How to create a numeric textbox in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268207/how-to-create-a-numeric-textbox-in-silverlight/1469073#1469073) for a more through implementation.

Comment: Ok. But in my case I can accept only number keys ie 0 to 9. So do I need to check the condition for every other keys in the keyboard ?

Comment: There are a lot of edge cases to consider, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268207/how-to-create-a-numeric-textbox-in-silverlight/1469073#1469073 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

keydown event handler:

KeyEventArgs e

e.Key is enum type Key, you can get character enum from this paramter

Comment: how get currently pressed key value ?. (if user press the key A, then I need the character A).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.key.aspxe.Key return enum . you can find key A 's value in the enum.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the user in entering digits only, set the `inputscope` to Number. See this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521152(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: The user might still have a hardware keyboard for example.

Comment: have you tested it? Personally i haven't tested the hardware keyboard. Please test and let me know

Comment: You can test using the emulator, focusing a text box and pressing the PageUp key on the computer keyboard will set it to hardware keyboard emulation and you'll be able to use the computer keyboard for input. I don't have a device with physical keyboard at my disposal now.

Comment: hmm correct. Its accepting all characters. A windows phone bug I guess